# How to add active class to menu from db laravel 6

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have a user menu which I am generating from a database, so as not to make changes to the file every time I need to add or remove a menu. This offers me great flexibility. I am having an issue with assigning an active class to the `li` elements when a user selects a menu. For instance, I have 3 levels, mainmenu, submenu and sub-submenu. I want the jquery function to work such that if a user clicks a sub-submenu, then the sub-submenu, submenu and mainmenu get the active class, if the user only click submenu, then the submenu and the mainmenu should have the active class. I have been trying to search the web for serveral days but I have not got any solution. My html code is as follows:

```
                  <?php foreach ($menus as $menu) { ?>
                    <li class='mainmenu'>
                        <a>
                            <i class="{{ $menu->menu_icon }}"></i>
                            <span class="link-title menu_hide">&nbsp; {{ $menu->menu_name }}</span>
                            <span class="fa arrow menu_hide"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($submenus as $submenu) { ?>
                            <?php if($submenu->is_level2 == '1' && $submenu->mainmenu_id == $menu->menu_id){ ?>
                            <li class="submenu">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                    &nbsp; {{ $submenu->submenu_name }}
                                    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul>
                                     <?php foreach ($subsubmenus as $subsubmenu) { ?>
                                        <?php if($subsubmenu->submenu_number == $submenu->submenu_number){ ?>
                                        <li class="subsubmenu">
                                            <a href="{{ url($subsubmenu->level2_link) }}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                                &nbsp; {{ $subsubmenu->level2_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php if($submenu->mainmenu_id == $menu->menu_id){ ?>
                                <li class="submenu">
                                    <a href="{{ url($submenu->submenu_link) }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                        &nbsp; {{ $submenu->submenu_name }}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php } } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Please try to help me get a suitable jquery function to do this. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Request::is('user/profile')
// Checks and returns true if current url is a match


<li class="@if(Request::is($subsubmenu->level2_link)) active @endif">
       <a href="{{ url($submenu->submenu_link) }}" >Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

You can use like this too.

```
class="@if(preg_match("/$module[0]/i",$uri)) active open @endif"
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Your help is highly appreciated.